# Javascript (ES6) convert number into string array of powers of 2

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, pow

Is there any smart inliner/one-liner (ES6) in transforming a number (integer) into a string array which got the number's bit position of its binary powers (pow(2,x))?
i.e.

```
13  =>    ["1","3","4"]    //   (pow(2,1) + pow(2,3)  + pow(2,4))  = 13
```

Comment: How have you done it in multiple lines?

Comment: Why `[1 ,3, 4]`? `2 ** 4` alone is 16, which is more than 13. Don't you mean `[0, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Look at the Array map function... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Big Sorry!  I was wrong. It should be of course ["1","4","8"]    (2¹ + 2² + 2³)

Comment: Now I tried something like this, and it seems to work:

`13..toString(2).split('').reverse().map((v, i) => (Math.pow(2, i) * v).toString()).filter(w => w != '0')`

Comment: @user1547821 That only gives you the exponentiated values, not the *powers* that you said you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

If you *actually* want an array of the powers of 2 which will result in the number, then for 13, you'd want:

```
2 ** 0 = 1
2 ** 2 = 4
2 ** 3 = 8
1 + 4 + 8 = 13
```

That is - `[0, 2, 3]` are the powers which result in 13.

`.toString(2)` turns a number into its binary equivalent, so you can take the elements of that string which are 1s:

```js
const num = 13;
const arr = [];
[...num.toString(2)].reverse().forEach((bit, i) => {
  if (bit === '1') {
    arr.push(i);
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```

Like all JS code, it's possible to squash into one line, but it'd be pretty silly - better to write clean and readable code without regard to line length:

```js
const num = 13; const arr = []; [...num.toString(2)].reverse().forEach((bit, i) => {   if (bit === '1') {   arr.push(i); } }); console.log(arr);
```